# Read XML file Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab

I want to extract the information from XML file. i tried the example from the Mathworks but it didn't work. Here is the sample information from file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<CS-info>
<cs name="abc">
<var name="a" unit="s1"/>
<var name="b" unit="s2"/>
.
.
</cs>
.
.
.
</CS-info>
```

when the "cs name" is selected the corresponding variable name and unit within this node should be extracted as cell array. Does any one has solution??
The expected output is

```
output={'a','s1';'b','s2';...};
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of [`xmlread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html), several example functions have been shown to help you parse an XML document. The code is copied as below in case it's removed -

```
function theStruct = parseXML(filename)
% PARSEXML Convert XML file to a MATLAB structure.
try
   tree = xmlread(filename);
catch
   error('Failed to read XML file %s.',filename);
end

% Recurse over child nodes. This could run into problems 
% with very deeply nested trees.
try
   theStruct = parseChildNodes(tree);
catch
   error('Unable to parse XML file %s.',filename);
end


% ----- Local function PARSECHILDNODES -----
function children = parseChildNodes(theNode)
% Recurse over node children.
children = [];
if theNode.hasChildNodes
   childNodes = theNode.getChildNodes;
   numChildNodes = childNodes.getLength;
   allocCell = cell(1, numChildNodes);

   children = struct(             ...
      'Name', allocCell, 'Attributes', allocCell,    ...
      'Data', allocCell, 'Children', allocCell);

    for count = 1:numChildNodes
        theChild = childNodes.item(count-1);
        children(count) = makeStructFromNode(theChild);
    end
end

% ----- Local function MAKESTRUCTFROMNODE -----
function nodeStruct = makeStructFromNode(theNode)
% Create structure of node info.

nodeStruct = struct(                        ...
   'Name', char(theNode.getNodeName),       ...
   'Attributes', parseAttributes(theNode),  ...
   'Data', '',                              ...
   'Children', parseChildNodes(theNode));

if any(strcmp(methods(theNode), 'getData'))
   nodeStruct.Data = char(theNode.getData); 
else
   nodeStruct.Data = '';
end

% ----- Local function PARSEATTRIBUTES -----
function attributes = parseAttributes(theNode)
% Create attributes structure.

attributes = [];
if theNode.hasAttributes
   theAttributes = theNode.getAttributes;
   numAttributes = theAttributes.getLength;
   allocCell = cell(1, numAttributes);
   attributes = struct('Name', allocCell, 'Value', ...
                       allocCell);

   for count = 1:numAttributes
      attrib = theAttributes.item(count-1);
      attributes(count).Name = char(attrib.getName);
      attributes(count).Value = char(attrib.getValue);
   end
end
```

It's easy to use,

```
str = 'http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/25047975';
x = parseXML(str);
```

To look for all `<cs>` nodes, you can perform a tree traversal and pick out attribute `name` and `unit` of all nodes with name `cs`.